# Order columns with mixed names in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a folder with file names as such:

> - 1-EXPERIMENT-CONDITION1 Drug 1
> - 2-EXPERIMENT-CONDITION2 Drug 2
> - ...
> - 10-EXPERIMENT-CONDITION4 Drug 3
> - 11-EXPERIMENT-CONDITION5 Drug 3
> - ...
> - 21-EXPERIMENT-CONDITION1 Drug 2

I have produced a loop for automatic data analysis but the plot part gives me troubles. I cannot force the column names since the loop is built to accept multiple data names as inputs.
Once I have produced a bar graph with ggplot2, column names are scrambles in a weird order:

> - 1-EXPERIMENT-CONDITION1 Drug 1
> - 10-EXPERIMENT-CONDITION4 Drug 3
> - 11-EXPERIMENT-CONDITION5 Drug 3
> - ...
> - 2-EXPERIMENT-CONDITION2 Drug 2
> - 21-EXPERIMENT-CONDITION1 Drug 2
> - ...

I tried to order alphabetically or from small to large, but this did not change.
I tried to transform values to numeric but this was even worse.

My question is: how can I rearrange column names in ggplot2 to have them alphabetically ordered?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprising it may be, but the list is already in alphabetical order. The list is first sorted by the first character - hence all items starting with 1 (1, 10, 19, 199...) come before items starting with 2 (2, 20...).

You have two options:

- (recommended) Rename your inputs to double digit format by adding 0, i.e. 1-EXPERIMENT to 01-EXPERIMENT and so on
- Reorder categories after import as described in an [excellent answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208679/order-bars-in-ggplot2-bar-graph)